# Add Include Expressions dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core and I have the following:

```
String expression = "Country;User;User.Country"
```

This indicates to include Country, User and User.Country in a query:

```
var q = context.Jobs
          .Include(x => x.Country)
          .Include(x => x.User).ThenInclude(x => x.Country);
```

I do not know what expression will contain. I just know it will be a list of entities, with or not child entities (ex: User.Country) and I need build the Include expression.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See duplicate, just split the string so you have an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is two way to call include method. one is with expression and the other is with string.

```
String expression = "Country;User;User.Country"

string includes = expression.split(';');

var q = context.Jobs;

foreach (string include in includes)
    q = q.Include(include);
```

Comment: And what if i need to include collection property and its corresponding properties? Here we need .ThenInclude() but this answer doesn't cover this situation.